# Why does href change after downloading page

Tags: python, html-parsing, anchor, html-parser

I'm making a web parser and some href are driving me crazy

```
resp = urllib.request.urlopen("http://portogruaro.trasparenza-valutazione-merito.it/storico-atti")
page = resp.read().decode('utf-8')
print(page)
```

I found this in the downloaded page:

```
<a.. href="http://portogruaro.trasparenza-valutazione-merito.it/storico-atti;jsessionid=BE0A764D125947680F3DC6F85760302A?p_p_id=ConsultazioneAtti_WAR_maggioliportalmasterdetailportlet&p_p_lifecycle=2&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_resource_id=downloadAllegato&p_p_cacheability=cacheLevelPage&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_ConsultazioneAtti_WAR_maggioliportalmasterdetailportlet_downloadTicket=oMrkWCwhyKWGcD67RyUPTMNzDbwk8ufAwUFVQ2_3Z4045lXXp1gcrKnaH7my84lD0jmgn_na5l1a5KnBtXxYtJYH7rbRP4GRdD53nB0MaBJSV6Ub1JDNoMnspbc2nmqr7a3ucdsOOBOUc4q0uTPd1Dg5ba1VE8DJ1kpf6C0eliencVxLYM8jPqxcSVokmrAjHqkHg4K3CFGZP9tGpCBTPQ"><i class="icon-download"></i> Allegato</a>
```

The href in the same anchor that you can see retrieving the same url with a browser is:

```
"http://portogruaro.trasparenza-valutazione-merito.it/storico-atti?p_p_id=ConsultazioneAtti_WAR_maggioliportalmasterdetailportlet&p_p_lifecycle=2&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_resource_id=downloadAllegato&p_p_cacheability=cacheLevelPage&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_ConsultazioneAtti_WAR_maggioliportalmasterdetailportlet_downloadTicket=HAxoH6d7h0JNRoKoi9sl4R-tsWdtMVoLeeZ8dU5rUQL74MQNMpCnqmBwxX4uNCXuMk4Clb6EzvrIaUXNY0G4q9YGlmebpMDTrR3255v6bLGOiIWVwvbnKiaOoapsGBqwP4JPIUN1R9G8ajAnurCaqTknyMJkVLiKaw0Z4wI61pgAzqjSGHatViGIGIXkrV7IN6EduMl29vAARMvaHhEJ5g"
```

;jsessionid is added because the bot doesn't manage cookies, but It's not the only change...why?

EDIT: Maybe a particular number of session triggers a specific action?

If you download the web-page, the downloaded href won't work if you click on it, but clicking on the href that you see in the browser's page (view-source:link) will work.

Comment: they might responde diferently depending on the user-agent but my guess is that the link is changes via javascript when you open it in the browser. your bot doesn't run javascript so it won't be changed.

Comment: hum...The original link downloaded a pdf when clicked...so I can't replicate the same action? Maybe a particular number of session triggers a specific action?

Answer (score 0):

> ;jsessionid is added because the bot doesn't manage cookies, but It's not the only change...why?

Hum ... apart from the ticket number and the `jsessionid` token, those are the same URL.

The parameters are *not* in the same order. But as far as I can tell, that doesn't change anything. Compare:

```
_ConsultazioneAtti_WAR_maggioliportalmasterdetailportlet_downloadTicket=oMrkWCwhyKWGcD67RyUPTMNzDbwk8ufAwUFVQ2_3Z4045lXXp1gcrKnaH7my84lD0jmgn_na5l1a5KnBtXxYtJYH7rbRP4GRdD53nB0MaBJSV6Ub1JDNoMnspbc2nmqr7a3ucdsOOBOUc4q0uTPd1Dg5ba1VE8DJ1kpf6C0eliencVxLYM8jPqxcSVokmrAjHqkHg4K3CFGZP9tGpCBTPQ
p_p_cacheability=cacheLevelPage
p_p_col_count=1
p_p_col_id=column-1
p_p_id=ConsultazioneAtti_WAR_maggioliportalmasterdetailportlet
p_p_lifecycle=2
p_p_mode=view
p_p_resource_id=downloadAllegato
p_p_state=normal
```

and

```
_ConsultazioneAtti_WAR_maggioliportalmasterdetailportlet_downloadTicket=HAxoH6d7h0JNRoKoi9sl4R-tsWdtMVoLeeZ8dU5rUQL74MQNMpCnqmBwxX4uNCXuMk4Clb6EzvrIaUXNY0G4q9YGlmebpMDTrR3255v6bLGOiIWVwvbnKiaOoapsGBqwP4JPIUN1R9G8ajAnurCaqTknyMJkVLiKaw0Z4wI61pgAzqjSGHatViGIGIXkrV7IN6EduMl29vAARMvaHhEJ5g"
p_p_cacheability=cacheLevelPage
p_p_col_count=1
p_p_col_id=column-1
p_p_id=ConsultazioneAtti_WAR_maggioliportalmasterdetailportlet
p_p_lifecycle=2
p_p_mode=view
p_p_resource_id=downloadAllegato
p_p_state=normal
```

Comment: It should download a pdf when you click it

Comment: When I posted the question, the first link didn't work, while the second worked. Now both of them don't work...I don't understand...

Comment: There is a session ID _and_ a download ticket. Changes are _great_ that this will somehow limit the downloads. As of myself, I think this is bad practice for interoperability. Unfortunately, quite frequent in the real world...

Comment: download tickets are different. I think that it is the reason why one link work and the other doesn't work.

Comment: If you download the web-page, the downloaded href won't work if you click on it, but clicking on the href that you see in the browser's page (view-source:link) will work.